# Checking if an array of objects contains value without looping?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Right now I have an array that looks like this

```
    const array = [
    {
      value: 'received',
      title: 'Hjá Birgja',
    },
    {
      value: 'pending',
      title: 'Yfirstandandi',
    },
    {
      value: 'processing',
      title: 'Í vinnslu',
    },
  ]
```

and I would like this to return true

```
if(array.includes('processing'){
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Why not just make a looping function somewhere and just call that? Then you don't have to write a new loop in your code each time -- just call your function that packages up that logic.

Comment: `array.includes('processing')`: the array don't include `processing`, it's one of its object that contains, you need to loop over the objects and find if one of them  have in its value the "processing"

Answer (score 0):

not exactly what you wanted since i'm not sure if you only wanted to search the value key but here's a solution

```
if (array.find(i => i.value === 'processing')) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Was hoping I could do it without having to loop but great solution. Always forget about .find

Comment: Yeah atleast this stops at the first thing it finds instead of continuing